# targeting element in parent window from iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I'm trying to close an iframe which opens in a pop up style. The button to close it is within the iframe. This is what I have inside the iframe:

```
$("#closeOverlayButton").click(function() {
    $('#closeOverlayButton', parent.document).closeOverlay();
});
```

The button has id of closeOverlayButton, and the function I'm calling is called closeOverlay (which works when it's not called from an iframe).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I don't think the `<iframe>` has access to the parent page.

Comment: Is the iframe-URI within the same domain as the parent URI? If not it will not work due to security issues.

Comment: @ReCaptcha I've done it before for sure so I know it's possible. Just can't remember how!

Comment: @Flügge it's the same URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$('#closeOverlayButton', window.parent.document).closeOverlay();
```

The ifram URI and parent URI should be in same domain.

Comment: Thanks @amir, no cigar though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following:

```
$("#closeOverlayButton").click(function() {
    $(".behindIframe", window.parent.document).fadeOut();
    $(".overlayDiv", window.parent.document).slideUp();
});
```

The two middle lines are basically the function that I was trying to run.